# How do I translate a list of rendered items with vue-i18n?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-i18n

I'm new to `vue.js` & `vue-i18n` and would like to know how to translate a rendered list of items with `v-for`.

This is for a **CakePHP** project using `vue.js`. I've tried referencing the locale inside the `data` function but this breaks the view.

**JS**

```
new Vue({
  i18n,
  el: '#my-form',
  data: {
    myList: [
      {key: 1, title: 'Option 01'},
      {key: 2, title: 'Option 02'},
      {key: 3, title: 'Option 03'}
    ]
  } 
})
```

```
<div>
  <label>{{ $t('label.options') }}</label>
  <div>
    <button v-for="option in myList">{{ title }}</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

I need to translate each option listed and replicate for other `selects` and `lists`. Any help is much appreciated as I'm unsure how to proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your `myList` into a computed property instead and you can utilize the options defined in i18n there by doing `title: this.$t(options.1)`.

https://codepen.io/Hiws/pen/xxKRpJR?editors=1011

Comment: Hi thanks this works for my example and in theory would work in my project but the key and value are the other way around. Which is similar to this:

```code
options: {
      'Mr': '1',
      'Miss': '2',
      'Mrs': '3'
    }
```

Can `vue-i18n` be configured to work this way? Appreciate any help, thanks.